# Limitar mes pra exportar relátorio

Tags: sql, oracle

Bom dia pessoal,

Eu tenho um sistema, e ele exporta relátorio do ANO da empresa. Eu queria limitar esse relatorio para 18 meses. Ou seja, o usuário pode fazer um relatorio de no máximo 18 meses, alem disso, teriam que entrar em contato com o administrador do sistema para que pudesse fazer o relatorio maior do que 18 meses.

A query que eu uso no banco para datas está crua, tem apenas isso:
`M.DTENCERRAMENTO = TO_DATE('01/01/1800 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')` Eu sou novo, não sei muito sobre banco ainda porque estou no inicio da faculdade. ALguem poderia me ajudar, a como eu consigo limitar essa data.

Comment: Utilize as funções de data para definir o período de seu relatório. Por exemplo: BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(M.DTENCERRAMENTO, -18) AND M.DTENCERRAMENTO. Talvez você também queira utilizar TRUNC(sua_data, 'MONTH').

Comment: ```M.DTENCERRAMENTO  BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/1800 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
ADD_MONTHS(M.DTENCERRAMENTO, -18) AND M.DTENCERRAMENTO```

Comment: Ficaria desse formato no caso?

Comment: Não. Seu comando está sintaticamente errado. Talvez a limitação da quantidade de meses deva estar em sua aplicação pois talvez ela é que saiba quem deve ou não ter um limite máximo de meses.

Comment: Não consegui resolver ainda. Brigado pela força anonimo.

Comment: COnsegui gente, brigado.